# Google apps script - automatically filter a specific range within a sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a spreadsheet and need a app script that automatically applies a filter to a specific range and hides values in a defined column.

[Screenshot of Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xF0cB.png)

I have previously used the below script, however, the filter range applies to the entire sheet.

My new requirement is for the filter range to only be applied to a specific range (in this case B3:L)

```
function setFilter() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var tab = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  var filter = {};
  filter.range = {
    sheetId: tab.getSheetId()
  };

  filter.criteria = {};
  // Which column to add the filter to
  var columnIndex = 0;
  filter['criteria'][columnIndex] = {
    'hiddenValues': ["✘"]
  };
  var request = {
    "setBasicFilter": {
      "filter": filter
    }
  };
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({'requests': [request]}, ss.getId());
}
```

How can I specify the range using this existing script?

I have attempted adding the following, but this does not work:

```
  var range = spreadsheet.getRange("B3:L")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to create a basic filter to cells "B3:L". When the cell value is `✘`, you want to hide the row.
- You want to achieve this using Sheets API with Google Apps Script.

In order to achieve your goal, when your showing script is modified, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function setFilter() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var tab = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  var filter = {};
  filter.range = {
    sheetId: tab.getSheetId(),
    startRowIndex: 2,
    startColumnIndex: 1,
    endColumnIndex: 12
  };
  filterSpecs = [];
  for (var i = filter.range.startColumnIndex; i <= filter.range.endColumnIndex; i++) {
    filterSpecs.push({ columnIndex: i, filterCriteria: { hiddenValues: ["✘"] } });
  }
  filter.filterSpecs = filterSpecs;
  var request = {
    "setBasicFilter": {
      "filter": filter
    }
  };
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ 'requests': [request] }, ss.getId());
}
```

- In this case, please set the gridrange to the range.
- Please set `hiddenValues: ["✘"]` to each column.
- When this script is run, when the cell value is `✘`, the row is hidden. And, the basic filter is set to "B3:L".

#### Reference:

- [SetBasicFilterRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#setbasicfilterrequest)